# Assigning To Property with Readonly Attribute not allowed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, game-center

I downloaded this tweejump app on [Github](https://github.com/haqu/tweejump). It worked fine with xcode 3.2.3, but now that I upgraded to xcode 4.2, it shows an error at this line:

```
cloud.opacity = 128;
```

Context:

```
- (void)initCloud {

    CGRect rect;
    switch(random()%3) {
        case 0: rect = CGRectMake(336,16,256,108); break;
        case 1: rect = CGRectMake(336,128,257,110); break;
        case 2: rect = CGRectMake(336,240,252,119); break;
    }   

    AtlasSpriteManager *spriteManager = (AtlasSpriteManager*)[self getChildByTag:kSpriteManager];
    AtlasSprite *cloud = [AtlasSprite spriteWithRect:rect spriteManager:spriteManager];
    [spriteManager addChild:cloud z:3 tag:currentCloudTag];

    cloud.opacity = 128;
}
```

It says `assigning to property with readonly attribute not allowed`.

What seems to be the problem? Does my upgrade to xcode 4.2 affect it?

I don't know what to do, because like I said, I just downloaded it...

Comment: i dont know sir.. i guess this version of cocos2d is not the latest one

Comment: You could change the `opacity` if you use CCSprite from Cocos2d 1.0, but you may have to rewrite everything.

Comment: waa is there no other way? -.- i think i cant do that

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but couldn't you just make the cloud image semi-transparent?

Comment: i tried to erase the line.. it worked but is it really ok?

Comment: Looking at the cocos2d source which is included in the Git repo you pointed to, the property is defined as: `@property (readonly) GLubyte opacity, r, g, b;`. So yes, it is readonly. Ah, but the `CocosNodeRGBA` protocol defines both getter and setter for the opacity property. So it's likely the compilers are picking up different things. (See my full answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the cocos2d source which is included in the Git repo you pointed to, the property is defined as:

```
@property (readonly) GLubyte opacity, r, g, b;.
```

So yes, it is readonly. However, the `CocosNodeRGBA` protocol defines both getter and setter for the opacity property. So it seems like the 2 different compilers are picking up different things where one notices that opacity can actually be set, but the other honours the property.

I think it should be safe enough to change the setting of opacity to:

```
[cloud setOpacity:128];
```

See here for more information: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/25332